# How to create a lag variable within each group?

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, dplyr

I have a data.table:

```
require(data.table)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.table(time = c(1:3, 1:4),
                   groups = c(rep(c("b", "a"), c(3, 4))),
                   value = rnorm(7))

data
#    groups time      value
# 1:      b    1 -0.6264538
# 2:      b    2  0.1836433
# 3:      b    3 -0.8356286
# 4:      a    1  1.5952808
# 5:      a    2  0.3295078
# 6:      a    3 -0.8204684
# 7:      a    4  0.4874291
```

I want to compute a lagged version of the "value" column, *within* each level of "groups".

The result should look like

```
#   groups time      value  lag.value
# 1      a    1  1.5952808         NA
# 2      a    2  0.3295078  1.5952808
# 3      a    3 -0.8204684  0.3295078
# 4      a    4  0.4874291 -0.8204684
# 5      b    1 -0.6264538         NA
# 6      b    2  0.1836433 -0.6264538
# 7      b    3 -0.8356286  0.1836433
```

I have tried to use `lag` directly:

```
data$lag.value <- lag(data$value)
```

...which clearly wouldn't work.

I have also tried:

```
unlist(tapply(data$value, data$groups, lag))
 a1         a2         a3         a4         b1         b2         b3 
 NA -0.1162932  0.4420753  2.1505440         NA  0.5894583 -0.2890288
```

Which is almost what I want. However the vector generated is ordered differently from the ordering in the data.table which is problematic.

What is the most efficient way to do this in base R, plyr, dplyr, and data.table?

Comment: sorry, combine with `group_by`

Comment: `unlist(by(data, data$groups, function(x) c(NA, head(x$value, -1))))` would be a base way

Comment: @xiaodai If you have just one column to do `lag` and the dataset is not that big, there won't be much difference in efficiency between `base R`, `plyr`, `data.table` methods.

Comment: @akrun Understand. However I actually simplied it. I actually need it for many columns and general solutions are preferred for the benefit of other useRs

Comment: @xiaodai I updated for multiple columns.  Regarding why `lag` is slow, it must depend on the code in `lag`.  You can check `getAnywhere('lag.default')[1]`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You could do this within `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 data[, lag.value:=c(NA, value[-.N]), by=groups]
  data
 #   time groups       value   lag.value
 #1:    1      a  0.02779005          NA
 #2:    2      a  0.88029938  0.02779005
 #3:    3      a -1.69514201  0.88029938
 #4:    1      b -1.27560288          NA
 #5:    2      b -0.65976434 -1.27560288
 #6:    3      b -1.37804943 -0.65976434
 #7:    4      b  0.12041778 -1.37804943
```

For multiple columns:

```
nm1 <- grep("^value", colnames(data), value=TRUE)
nm2 <- paste("lag", nm1, sep=".")
data[, (nm2):=lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA, x[-.N])), by=groups, .SDcols=nm1]
 data
#    time groups      value     value1      value2  lag.value lag.value1
#1:    1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247  1.12493092         NA         NA
#2:    2      b  0.1836433  0.5757814 -0.04493361 -0.6264538  0.7383247
#3:    3      b -0.8356286 -0.3053884 -0.01619026  0.1836433  0.5757814
#4:    1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812  0.94383621         NA         NA
#5:    2      a  0.3295078  0.3898432  0.82122120  1.5952808  1.5117812
#6:    3      a -0.8204684 -0.6212406  0.59390132  0.3295078  0.3898432
#7:    4      a  0.4874291 -2.2146999  0.91897737 -0.8204684 -0.6212406
#    lag.value2
#1:          NA
#2:  1.12493092
#3: -0.04493361
#4:          NA
#5:  0.94383621
#6:  0.82122120
#7:  0.59390132
```

#### Update

From `data.table` versions >= `v1.9.5`, we can use `shift` with `type` as `lag` or `lead`.  By default, the type is `lag`.

```
data[, (nm2) :=  shift(.SD), by=groups, .SDcols=nm1]
#   time groups      value     value1      value2  lag.value lag.value1
#1:    1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247  1.12493092         NA         NA
#2:    2      b  0.1836433  0.5757814 -0.04493361 -0.6264538  0.7383247
#3:    3      b -0.8356286 -0.3053884 -0.01619026  0.1836433  0.5757814
#4:    1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812  0.94383621         NA         NA
#5:    2      a  0.3295078  0.3898432  0.82122120  1.5952808  1.5117812
#6:    3      a -0.8204684 -0.6212406  0.59390132  0.3295078  0.3898432
#7:    4      a  0.4874291 -2.2146999  0.91897737 -0.8204684 -0.6212406
#    lag.value2
#1:          NA
#2:  1.12493092
#3: -0.04493361
#4:          NA
#5:  0.94383621
#6:  0.82122120
#7:  0.59390132
```

If you need the reverse, use `type=lead`

```
nm3 <- paste("lead", nm1, sep=".")
```

Using the original dataset

```
  data[, (nm3) := shift(.SD, type='lead'), by = groups, .SDcols=nm1]
  #  time groups      value     value1      value2 lead.value lead.value1
  #1:    1      b -0.6264538  0.7383247  1.12493092  0.1836433   0.5757814
  #2:    2      b  0.1836433  0.5757814 -0.04493361 -0.8356286  -0.3053884
  #3:    3      b -0.8356286 -0.3053884 -0.01619026         NA          NA
  #4:    1      a  1.5952808  1.5117812  0.94383621  0.3295078   0.3898432
  #5:    2      a  0.3295078  0.3898432  0.82122120 -0.8204684  -0.6212406
  #6:    3      a -0.8204684 -0.6212406  0.59390132  0.4874291  -2.2146999
  #7:    4      a  0.4874291 -2.2146999  0.91897737         NA          NA
 #   lead.value2
 #1: -0.04493361
 #2: -0.01619026
 #3:          NA
 #4:  0.82122120
 #5:  0.59390132
 #6:  0.91897737
 #7:          NA
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(1)
 data <- data.table(time =c(1:3,1:4),groups = c(rep(c("b","a"),c(3,4))),
             value = rnorm(7), value1=rnorm(7), value2=rnorm(7))
```

Comment: Am wondering why data[, lag.value:=lag(value)), by=groups] which gives the same result is slower than your solution?

Comment: How would I do this, but in reverse? In other words, instead of lagging by one (taking the previous row) it would be ahead by one (taking the following row value)? Thank you for the great entry!

Comment: Is it also possible to lag by more than one value? (i.e. getting `data[, lag.value.1:=c(NA, lag.value[-.N]), by=groups]` without calculating `lag.value`?)

Comment: @greyBag I didn't understand what you wanted.  In the post it shows `shift(.SD)` which is calculating the lag for more than one column by specifying the columns in the  `.SDcols`.  DId you meant to get two lags for a single column.  In that case `data[, shift(value, 1:2), by=groups]`

Comment: @akrun from your reply is assume the solution I am looking for is going to be `data[,  shift(value, 2), by=groups]` (but I can't the devel version to work yet). But to clarify, my question was how to lag a single column by 2 values rather than by 1 value. The first 3 rows of the output I need are: `data.table(time = c(1,2,3), groups = c(a,a,a), value = c(0.02779005, 0.88029938, -1.69514201), lag.value = c(NA, NA, 0.02779005))`

Comment: @greyBag Yes, the `data[, shift(value, 2), by=groups]` get the result, but if you are not able to do that, then we hve to lag by 2. i.e.  `dt[, lag(value, 2), by=groups]`

Comment: @akrun thanks, I'll see if I can make it work. I posted the question here in the mean time (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721023/lag-a-column-in-data-table-by-more-than-1-value)!

Comment: When i try this I get `Error:Unused arguments (by=groups, .SDcols=nm1)` 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @thentangler not clear.  I tested it once again and it is working fine for me.  Please check if you have a `data.table` object or not

Comment: Sorry about that. I did convert it to data.table object, but I am now getting the error: `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'` 
This is the code Im using: `nm1 <- grep("Time$", colnames(df), value=TRUE)
nm2 <- paste("lag", nm1, sep="_")
df[, (nm2) := shift(.SD), by=groups, .SDcols=nm1]` The columns im lagging are of `POSIXct` datatype, could that be the issue?

Comment: @thentangler is the error based on the same example data in the post or a different one (as the code is working fine with example).  If it is `POSIXlt`, then it is a list column

Comment: The data is different as I’m doing the operation on timestamps column of data type POSIXct. 
I guess the approach should be different in that case. I’ll try posting it as a separate question. 
Thank you for being kind enough to follow up :)

Answer (score 103):

Using package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- 
    data %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    mutate(lag.value = dplyr::lag(value, n = 1, default = NA))
```

gives

```
> data
Source: local data table [7 x 4]
Groups: groups

  time groups       value   lag.value
1    1      a  0.07614866          NA
2    2      a -0.02784712  0.07614866
3    3      a  1.88612245 -0.02784712
4    1      b  0.26526825          NA
5    2      b  1.23820506  0.26526825
6    3      b  0.09276648  1.23820506
7    4      b -0.09253594  0.09276648
```

As noted by @BrianD, this implicitly assumes that value is sorted by group already. If not, either sort it by group, or use the `order_by` argument in `lag`. Also note that due to an [existing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by) with some versions of dplyr, for safety, arguments and the namespace should be explicitly given.

Comment: How do you use this while looping over all the variables you need to create a lag for ?

Comment: do you mean you have multiple columns you wish to do the lag operation over? Check out `mutate_each`, `mutate_all`, `mutate_at` etc commands

Comment: does this solution assume that the source dataset is pre-sorted appropriately?

Comment: @BrianD yes it does, but this is implicit in the OP's comment that they want `value` lagged by group.

Comment: @Alex I was just thinking that if the `time` variable wasn't sorted ahead of time (as might be the case in other users datasets who are reading this), there is no explicit sorting in this code.  Might be safer to specify the sort order explicitly like: `lag(value, 1, order_by=time)`

Comment: @BrianD I do not think there is any confusion as `lag` in my mind means take previous values and shift them by `n` positions, but it is useful to note that you can pass an ordering argument to lag, thanks.

Comment: @Alex Is it possible to do some arithmetic operation within lag function? For example, can I subtract every row from the value in the first row - groupwise?

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to complement the previous answers by mentioning two ways in which I approach this problem in the important case **when you are not guaranteed that each group has data for every time period**. That is, you still have a regularly spaced time series, but there might be missings here and there. I will focus on two ways to improve the `dplyr` solution.

We start with the same data that you used...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
data_df = data.frame(time   = c(1:3, 1:4),
                     groups = c(rep(c("b", "a"), c(3, 4))),
                     value  = rnorm(7))
data_df
#>   time groups      value
#> 1    1      b -0.6264538
#> 2    2      b  0.1836433
#> 3    3      b -0.8356286
#> 4    1      a  1.5952808
#> 5    2      a  0.3295078
#> 6    3      a -0.8204684
#> 7    4      a  0.4874291
```

... but now we delete a couple of rows

```
data_df = data_df[-c(2, 6), ]
data_df
#>   time groups      value
#> 1    1      b -0.6264538
#> 3    3      b -0.8356286
#> 4    1      a  1.5952808
#> 5    2      a  0.3295078
#> 7    4      a  0.4874291
```

#### Simple `dplyr` solution no longer works

```
data_df %>% 
  arrange(groups, time) %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  mutate(lag.value = lag(value)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>    time groups  value lag.value
#>   <int> <fct>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 a       1.60     NA    
#> 2     2 a       0.330     1.60 
#> 3     4 a       0.487     0.330
#> 4     1 b      -0.626    NA    
#> 5     3 b      -0.836    -0.626
```

You see that, although we don't have the value for the case `(group = 'a', time = '3')`, the above still shows a value for the lag in the case of `(group = 'a', time = '4')`, which is actually the value at `time = 2`.

#### Correct `dplyr` solution

The idea is that we add the missing (group, time) combinations. This is **VERY** memory-inefficient when you have lots of possible (groups, time) combinations, but the values are sparsely captured.

```
dplyr_correct_df = expand.grid(
  groups = sort(unique(data_df$groups)),
  time   = seq(from = min(data_df$time), to = max(data_df$time))
) %>% 
  left_join(data_df, by = c("groups", "time")) %>% 
  arrange(groups, time) %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  mutate(lag.value = lag(value)) %>% 
  ungroup()
dplyr_correct_df
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   groups  time   value lag.value
#>   <fct>  <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 a          1   1.60     NA    
#> 2 a          2   0.330     1.60 
#> 3 a          3  NA         0.330
#> 4 a          4   0.487    NA    
#> 5 b          1  -0.626    NA    
#> 6 b          2  NA        -0.626
#> 7 b          3  -0.836    NA    
#> 8 b          4  NA        -0.836
```

Notice that we now have a NA at `(group = 'a', time = '4')`, which should be the expected behaviour. Same with `(group = 'b', time = '3')`.

#### Tedious but also correct solution using the class `zoo::zooreg`

This solution should work better in terms of memory when the amount of cases is very large, because instead of filling the missing cases with NA's, it uses indices.

```
library(zoo)

zooreg_correct_df = data_df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # nest the data for each group
  # should work for multiple groups variables
  nest(-groups, .key = "zoo_ob") %>%
  mutate(zoo_ob = lapply(zoo_ob, function(d) {

    # create zooreg objects from the individual data.frames created by nest
    z = zoo::zooreg(
      data      = select(d,-time),
      order.by  = d$time,
      frequency = 1
    ) %>% 
      # calculate lags
      # we also ask for the 0'th order lag so that we keep the original value
      zoo:::lag.zooreg(k = (-1):0) # note the sign convention is different

    # recover df's from zooreg objects
    cbind(
      time = as.integer(zoo::index(z)),
      zoo:::as.data.frame.zoo(z)
    )

  })) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  # format values
  select(groups, time, value = value.lag0, lag.value = `value.lag-1`) %>% 
  arrange(groups, time) %>% 
  # eliminate additional periods created by lag
  filter(time <= max(data_df$time))
zooreg_correct_df
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   groups  time   value lag.value
#>   <fct>  <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 a          1   1.60     NA    
#> 2 a          2   0.330     1.60 
#> 3 a          3  NA         0.330
#> 4 a          4   0.487    NA    
#> 5 b          1  -0.626    NA    
#> 6 b          2  NA        -0.626
#> 7 b          3  -0.836    NA    
#> 8 b          4  NA        -0.836
```

Finally, lets check that both correct solutions are actually equal:

```
all.equal(dplyr_correct_df, zooreg_correct_df)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Has anything happened to dplyr? Using either of the two solutions does not lag anything in my case. It just replicates the original values in a different column

Comment: The dplyr version still works for me as of this moment, except for one minor change, I need to indicate the seq "by" parameter, which can be explored with ?seq.Date. I note this operation is EXTREMELY common.

Comment: The example as it is right now still works for me. The fix @RegressForward used is necessary if you have Date data instead of ints (as in this example). There is no default increment for building sequences of Dates.

Answer (score 10):

In base R, this will do the job:

```
data$lag.value <- c(NA, data$value[-nrow(data)])
data$lag.value[which(!duplicated(data$groups))] <- NA
```

The first line adds a string of lagged (+1) observations. The second string corrects the first entry of each group, as the lagged observation is from previous group.

Note that `data` is of format `data.frame` to not use `data.table`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to make sure that you avoided any issue with ordering the data, you can do this, using dplyr, manually with something like:

```
df <- data.frame(Names = c(rep('Dan',50),rep('Dave',100)),
            Dates = c(seq(1,100,by=2),seq(1,100,by=1)),
            Values = rnorm(150,0,1))

df <- df %>% group_by(Names) %>% mutate(Rank=rank(Dates),
                                    RankDown=Rank-1)

df <- df %>% left_join(select(df,Rank,ValueDown=Values,Names),by=c('RankDown'='Rank','Names')
) %>% select(-Rank,-RankDown)

head(df)
```

Or alternatively I like the idea of putting it in a function with a chosen grouping variable(s), ranking column (like Date or otherwise), and chosen number of lags. This also requires lazyeval as well as dplyr.

```
groupLag <- function(mydf,grouping,ranking,lag){
  df <- mydf
  groupL <- lapply(grouping,as.symbol)

  names <- c('Rank','RankDown')
  foos <- list(interp(~rank(var),var=as.name(ranking)),~Rank-lag)

  df <- df %>% group_by_(.dots=groupL) %>% mutate_(.dots=setNames(foos,names))

  selectedNames <- c('Rank','Values',grouping)
  df2 <- df %>% select_(.dots=selectedNames)
  colnames(df2) <- c('Rank','ValueDown',grouping)

  df <- df %>% left_join(df2,by=c('RankDown'='Rank',grouping)) %>% select(-Rank,-RankDown)

  return(df)
}

groupLag(df,c('Names'),c('Dates'),1)
```