# dplyr: lead() and lag() wrong when used with group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the lead() and lag() element in each group, but had some wrong results.

For example, data is like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(name=rep(c('Al','Jen'),3),
                score=rep(c(100, 80, 60),2))
df
```

Data:

```
  name score
1   Al   100
2  Jen    80
3   Al    60
4  Jen   100
5   Al    80
6  Jen    60
```

Now I try to find out lead() and lag() scores for each person.
If I sort it using arrange(), I can get the correct answer:

```
df %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(next.score = lead(score),
         before.score = lag(score) )
```

OUTPUT1:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: name

      name score next.score before.score
    1   Al   100         60           NA
    2   Al    60         80          100
    3   Al    80         NA           60
    4  Jen    80        100           NA
    5  Jen   100         60           80
    6  Jen    60         NA          100
```

Without arrange(), the result is wrong:

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(next.score = lead(score),
         before.score = lag(score) )
```

OUTPUT2:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: name

  name score next.score before.score
1   Al   100         80           NA
2  Jen    80         60           NA
3   Al    60        100           80
4  Jen   100         80           60
5   Al    80         NA          100
6  Jen    60         NA           80
```

E.g., in 1st line, Al's next.score should be 60 (3rd line).

Anybody know why this happened? Why arrange() affects the result (the values, not just about the order)? Thanks~

Comment: @DavidArenburg it's not the sorting, the OP asks why the result is 80 when in the original data frame the next result is 60. It's like Jen's result was picked instead of Al's

Comment: And I can't repro. Which version of R are you using? I get `1   Al   100         60           NA` with R 3.1.2 on Windows 7

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah you are right. I didn't notice that.

Comment: I can reproduce the weird results (`0.4.1.9000`). I think (after a quick, groggy-eyed glance at the source of the series of function calls) it's because the underlying code is going by actual overall row-index instead of the relative row-index. That might explain `lead` (I think `pmin` is the place of the weirdness), but not sure what's going on with `lag` (didn't look there).

Comment: I had 0.3.0.2 which I installed yesterday, and I can't repro the results. Default mirror was 0-Cloud

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I bleeding edge the hadleyverse every couple of days from devtools/github.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the latest version 0.4.1 of `dplyr` and was already reported [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/925)

Comment: @hrbrmstr no, just 0 seems to be far behind any other mirror. And I get the same error now.

Comment: I see thanks! I think for now I can sort the data first using arrange() to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It seems you have to pass additional argument to lag and lead functions. When I run your function without arrange, but with order_by added, everything seems to be ok.

```
df %>%
group_by(name) %>%
mutate(next.score = lead(score, order_by=name),
before.score = lag(score, order_by=name))
```

Output:

```
  name score next.score before.score
1   Al   100         60           NA
2  Jen    80        100           NA
3   Al    60         80          100
4  Jen   100         60           80
5   Al    80         NA           60
6  Jen    60         NA          100
```

My sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250        LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1  DBI_0.3.1       lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5                parallel_3.1.1  Rcpp_0.11.5    
[7] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: I am working with a similar case of lag, but with one change - multiple columns for grouping and ordering! If there were multiple columns in group_by and order_by, how different will the answer be? I tried passing vectors but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 24):

It may happen that `stats::lag` is used instead (e.g. when restoring environments with the `session` package). This can easly slip through unnoticed as it it won't throw an error when being used as in the question. Double-check by simply typing `lag`, use `conflicted` package, or disambiguate the function call by calling `dplyr::lag` instead.

The same could happen for `plyr::mutate`, in case you might have loaded `plyr` package in your session. So make sure you're also calling `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: many packages have a lag function - as this comment states, verifying / disambiguation is crucial unless you are simply relying upon a small set of packages or base R + dplyr alone.

Comment: I wasted the last 2 hours trying to understand what was suddenly wrong in a code that was supposed to run, before finding this GodSend reply stressing dplyr:mutate and dplyr:lag. This needs much more attention. Thank you sir.

Comment: Reiterating what everyone else has said. Spent so long wondering when a very simple piece of code suddenly isn't working. Very frustrating! Your answer is so simple, yet so easy to overlook, and worked a treat!!! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Using order_by is good when you have only one grouping variable. In case of multiple grouping variable, I could not find any solution except, writing and reading the table to get rid of grouping variables. It worked pretty well for me, but its efficiency depends on the size of table.

Comment: I created a dummy grouping variable for this case to allow using order_by: `mutate(grouping=sprintf("%04d-%04d",var1,var2)) %>% mutate(next.score = lead(score, order_by=grouping) %>% select(-grouping)`