# Lagging variable by group does not work in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I'm desperately trying to lag a variable by group. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by) post that deals with essentially the same problem I'm facing, but the solution does not work for me, no idea why.

This is my problem:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(monthvec = c(rep(1:2, 2), rep(3:5, 3)))
df <- df %>%
       arrange(monthvec) %>%
       mutate(growth=ifelse(monthvec==1, 0.3,
                   ifelse(monthvec==2, 0.5,
                          ifelse(monthvec==3, 0.7,
                                 ifelse(monthvec==4, 0.1,
                                        ifelse(monthvec==5, 0.6,NA))))))

df%>%
   group_by(monthvec) %>%
   mutate(lag.growth = lag(growth, order_by=monthvec))

Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
Groups: monthvec [5]

monthvec growth lag.growth
  <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1         1    0.3         NA
2         1    0.3        0.3
3         2    0.5         NA
4         2    0.5        0.5
5         3    0.7         NA
6         3    0.7        0.7
7         3    0.7        0.7
8         4    0.1         NA
9         4    0.1        0.1
10        4    0.1        0.1
11        5    0.6         NA
12        5    0.6        0.6
13        5    0.6        0.6
```

This is what I'd like it to be in the end:

```
df$lag.growth <- c(NA, NA, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7,0.7,0.7, 0.1,0.1,0.1)

   monthvec growth lag.growth
1         1    0.3         NA
2         1    0.3         NA
3         2    0.5        0.3
4         2    0.5        0.3
5         3    0.7        0.5
6         3    0.7        0.5
7         3    0.7        0.5
8         4    0.1        0.7
9         4    0.1        0.7
10        4    0.1        0.7 
11        5    0.6        0.1
12        5    0.6        0.1
13        5    0.6        0.1
```

I believe that one problem is that my groups are not of equal length...

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: What happens if `growth` has multiple values in a month?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you're aiming at...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea. We group by `monthvec` in order to get the number of rows (`cnt`) of each group. We ungroup and use the first value of `cnt` as the size of the lag. We regroup on `monthvec` and replace the values in each group with the first value of each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(monthvec) %>% 
 mutate(cnt = n()) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 mutate(lag.growth = lag(growth, first(cnt))) %>% 
 group_by(monthvec) %>% 
 mutate(lag.growth = first(lag.growth)) %>% 
 select(-cnt)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 13 x 3
> # Groups:   monthvec [5]
>    monthvec growth lag.growth
>       <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
>  1        1    0.3         NA
>  2        1    0.3         NA
>  3        2    0.5        0.3
>  4        2    0.5        0.3
>  5        3    0.7        0.5
>  6        3    0.7        0.5
>  7        3    0.7        0.5
>  8        4    0.1        0.7
>  9        4    0.1        0.7
> 10        4    0.1        0.7
> 11        5    0.6        0.1
> 12        5    0.6        0.1
> 13        5    0.6        0.1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You may join your original data with a dataframe with a shifted "monthvec".

```
left_join(df, df %>% mutate(monthvec = monthvec + 1) %>% unique(), by = "monthvec")

#    monthvec growth.x growth.y
# 1         1      0.3       NA
# 2         1      0.3       NA
# 3         2      0.5      0.3
# 4         2      0.5      0.3
# 5         3      0.7      0.5
# 6         3      0.7      0.5
# 7         3      0.7      0.5
# 8         4      0.1      0.7
# 9         4      0.1      0.7
# 10        4      0.1      0.7
# 11        5      0.6      0.1
# 12        5      0.6      0.1
# 13        5      0.6      0.1
```