# dplyr lead/lag with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, lead

Do not understand why I the lead and lag functions ignore the group by.
Here's a simple example (in reality I need to group by 5 columns).
​

```
# Dummy DataSet
df <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
                 order = c(3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4),
                 value = c(15, 22, 43, 31, 25, 11, 37, 24, 18, 9))    

"group" "order" "value"
"a" 3   15
"a" 4   22
"a" 2   43
"a" 5   31
"a" 1   25
"b" 1   11
"b" 3   37
"b" 4   24
"b" 2   18
"b" 4   9
```

Tried this but even the order by doesn't work here

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(previous = dplyr::lag(value, n=1, default=NA, order_by = order))
```

​
Then tried to arrange beforehand.

```
df %>% 
    arrange(group, order) %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(previous = dplyr::lag(value, n=1, default=NA))

"group" "order" "value" "previous"
"a" 1   25  NA
"a" 2   43  25
"a" 3   15  43
"a" 4   22  15
"a" 5   31  22
"b" 1   11  31
"b" 2   18  11
"b" 3   37  18
"b" 4   24  37
"b" 4   9   24
```

​
Which fixes the sorting but is still ignoring the group by as b 1 should be NA not 31.
​
Am I missing something obvious or can lag/lead and group_by not be combined like this?

​
It would work in SQL with

```
LAG(value, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY order)
```

​
​
Apologies if formatting is poor, not posted code questions before.

Comment: Oh, as simple as that, spent ages trying different things aha.

Restarted R and updated dplyr from 0.7.4 to 0.7.6.

Thanks Both

Comment: Actually, the issue persists in `plyr`. So if for some reason you import both `dplyr` and `plyr`, import `dplyr` last. Otherwise `plyr` will overwrite `dplyr`'s `lag` function leading to the issue described here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr: lead() and lag() wrong when used with group\_by()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by)