# Group_by + lag repeat the same values for all groups in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm making a Shiny app in which the user can generate a column in a table by clicking on a `checkboxInput`. The column I would like to create contains the lagged value of the column already present in the table.

The code below shows a reproducible example: there are two individuals (`A` and `B`) and three time periods (`1`, `2` and `3`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

data <- head(mtcars)
data$time <- rep(seq(1:3))
data$ID <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("choice", "Select a column", choices = c("mpg", "drat", "hp"), multiple = F),
  checkboxInput("lag", "Compute lag value"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data2 <- reactive({
    lagged_name <- paste0(input$choice, "_lagged")
    if (input$lag){
      data %>%
        select(ID, time, input$choice) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        mutate(!!all_of(lagged_name) := lag(data[, input$choice]))
    }
    else {
      data %>%
        select(ID, time, input$choice)
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run this code and click on the checkbox, I have the error:

> Warning: Error in : Column `mpg_lagged` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by), I corrected it by adding `order_by = ID` in the `lag` function but now there is another problem: for individual `1`, it creates the right lagged values, but then those values are repeated for individual `2` as well whereas they do not correspond.

I tried a similar example without the Shiny environment and the right output is produced so I suppose this problem comes from the inputs or reactive environment.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some (minor) issues with non-standard evaluation (NSE) inside your `reactive` data object. Fixing these gives

```r
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

data <- head(mtcars)
data$time <- rep(seq(1:3))
data$ID <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("choice", "Select a column", choices = c("mpg", "drat", "hp"), multiple = F),
  checkboxInput("lag", "Compute lag value"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data2 <- reactive({
    lagged_name <- paste0(input$choice, "_lagged")
    if (input$lag){
      data %>%
        select(ID, time, input$choice) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
        mutate(!!lagged_name := lag(!!sym(input$choice)))
    }
    else {
      data %>%
        select(ID, time, input$choice)
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

resulting in

[image]

Explanation:

- `select` takes both evaluated symbols and strings as arguments, so we can directly pass `input$choice` as an argument to `select`.
- To construct a new column with a name from a variable we need to evaluate the variable as `!!lagged_name`; we then must use `:=` (instead of `=`) to do the assignment, as R's grammar does not allow expressions as argument names (the lhs of the assignment). Finally, inside the `lag` function we first must convert `input$choice` to a symbol with `sym` and then evaluate the symbol with `!!`. That's because of `dplyr`'s NSE, where you would write e.g. `mtcars %>% mutate(col = lag(wt))` and not `mtcars %>% mutate(col = lag("wt"))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works well. I'm not very comfortable with NSE (not even sure of what it means) because I used it from another post on SO, could you explain me a little bit more or redirect me on an article dedicated to it?

Comment: Hi @bretauv; I've added some explanations, hopefully it's useful. The best reference for some more reading is IMO Hadley's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/), specifically the section on quasiquotation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is useful. If I understand well, ```sym``` is necessary to remove the quotation marks that come automatically with ```input```, right? I will read hadley's book, thanks also for the reference