# Creating lag variable using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

What I want to perform:
If `hmonth=2` and `hyear=2000`, subtract each observation of `wageratio.female` from that of `hmonth=1` and `hyear=2000`.
If `hmonth=2` and `hyear=2001`, subtract each observation of `wageratio.female` from that of `hmonth=1` and `hyear=2001`.
Repeat for all `hmonth` and `hyear`.
Create a variable called `wageratio.lags` for the differences.

Below is a small section of my attempt at `for` loop. Should I be using `for` loop to achieve my desired output?

```
differences = list()

for i in range(len(hmonth)):
    # Check if the current pair is (2, 2000) or (2, 2001)
    if hmonth[i] == 2:
        if hyear[i] == 2000:
            # Subtract each observation of wageratio_female from that of hmonth=1 and hyear=2000
            difference = wageratio_female[i] - wageratio_female[hmonth.index(1)]
            differences.append(difference)
        elif hyear[i] == 2001:
            # Subtract each observation of wageratio_female from that of hmonth=1 and hyear=2001
            difference = wageratio_female[i] - wageratio_female[hmonth.index(1)]
            differences.append(difference)
Error: unexpected symbol in "for i"
```

Desired output:

| hmonth | hyear | wageratio.female | wageratio.lags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | -0.43 | -0.01 |
| 1 | 2001 | 0.18 | -0.62 |
| 2 | 2000 | -0.44 | 0.12 |
| 2 | 2001 | -0.44 | -0.47 |
| 3 | 2000 | -0.32 | -0.45 |
| 3 | 2001 | -0.91 | 0.70 |
| 4 | 2000 | -0.77 | 1.24 |
| 4 | 2001 | -0.21 | NA |
| 5 | 2000 | 0.47 | NA |

```
df <- data.frame(
  wageratio_female = c(-0.43, 0.18, -0.44, -0.44, -0.32, -0.91, -0.77, -0.21, 0.47),
  hmonth = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5),
  hyear = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000)
 )
```

Comment: Is this R or python? Your data looks like R via `dput()` but your code looks like `python`. You show the desired output, but what exactly is the input? So you just have separate vectors, or do you have a data.frame?

Comment: I am using R. I have a dataframe that consists of these three variables and other variables. I am using separate vectors to simplify the problem. @MrFlick

Comment: edits have been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `dplyr` `lead/lag` functions to do this without a loop. For example

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(hyear) %>% 
  arrange(hmonth) %>% 
  mutate(wageratio.lags = lead(wageratio_female) - wageratio_female) %>%
  ungroup()
```

produces

```
  wageratio_female     hmonth      hyear    wageratio.lags
             <dbl> <hvn_lbll> <hvn_lbll>   <dbl>
1            -0.43          1       2000 -0.0100
2             0.18          1       2001 -0.62  
3            -0.44          2       2000  0.12  
4            -0.44          2       2001 -0.47  
5            -0.32          3       2000 -0.45  
6            -0.91          3       2001  0.7   
7            -0.77          4       2000  1.24  
8            -0.21          4       2001 NA     
9             0.47          5       2000 NA
```

Comment: This is perfect! Any idea why am I getting this? I'm using the exact same df provided in this post Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `wageratio.lags = lead(wageratio_female) - wageratio_female`.
ℹ In group 1: `hyear = 2000`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'lead' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: This might resolve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744474/no-applicable-method-for-lead-applied-to-an-object-of-class-cdouble-nume