# offset date column content by id

Tags: r, contentoffset

I have a dataset as follows

```
 Id     Date1                
 121    2011-01-03
 121    2011-01-03
 121    2011-04-02
 121    2011-08-14
 121    2012-01-14
 121    2012-05-12
 975    2011-02-01
 975    2011-02-01
 975    2011-06-14
 975    2012-01-06
 975    2012-04-19
 975    2012-09-25
```

What I want to create is an output like this below, where the new Date2 column is offset by one value based on the id,

```
 Id     Date1        Date2                         
 121    2011-01-03   2011-01-03
 121    2011-01-03   2011-04-02
 121    2011-04-02   2011-08-14
 121    2011-08-14   2012-01-14
 121    2012-01-14   2012-05-12 
 121    2012-05-12   NA

 975    2011-02-01   2011-02-01
 975    2011-02-01   2011-06-14
 975    2011-06-14   2012-01-06
 975    2012-01-06   2012-04-19
 975    2012-04-19   2012-09-25
 975    2012-09-25   NA
```

Date2 column row 2 for Id 121 i.e 2011-01-03 becomes Date1 column, row1 value for Id 121.

Date2 column row3 for Id 121 i.e 2011-04-02 becomes Date1 column, row2 value for Id 121....so on...This should happen by id.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can group by 'Id' and create a new column 'Date2' using `mutate` and `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Id) %>% 
     mutate(Date2= lead(Date1))
# Id      Date1      Date2
#1  121 2011-01-03 2011-01-03
#2  121 2011-01-03 2011-04-02
#3  121 2011-04-02 2011-08-14
#4  121 2011-08-14 2012-01-14
#5  121 2012-01-14 2012-05-12
#6  121 2012-05-12         NA
#7  975 2011-02-01 2011-02-01
#8  975 2011-02-01 2011-06-14
#9  975 2011-06-14 2012-01-06
#10 975 2012-01-06 2012-04-19
#11 975 2012-04-19 2012-09-25
#12 975 2012-09-25         NA
```

Or a similar option using the devel version of `data.table` will be converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), group by 'Id', and use the `shift` function with option `type='lead'`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, Date2:= shift(Date1, type='lead') , by = Id][]
#      Id      Date1      Date2
# 1: 121 2011-01-03 2011-01-03
# 2: 121 2011-01-03 2011-04-02
# 3: 121 2011-04-02 2011-08-14
# 4: 121 2011-08-14 2012-01-14
# 5: 121 2012-01-14 2012-05-12
# 6: 121 2012-05-12         NA
# 7: 975 2011-02-01 2011-02-01
# 8: 975 2011-02-01 2011-06-14
# 9: 975 2011-06-14 2012-01-06
#10: 975 2012-01-06 2012-04-19
#11: 975 2012-04-19 2012-09-25
#12: 975 2012-09-25         NA
```

Or we can use `ave` from `base R`.  We group by 'Id' column, remove the first observation and concatenate with `NA` at the end.

```
df1$Date2 <- with(df1, ave(Date1, Id, FUN=function(x) c(x[-1], NA)))
```

Comment: I wonder if you could just close this with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/r-how-to-create-a-lag-variable-for-each-by-group

Comment: @DavidArenburg Technically, it is the lag in the link (though in one of the replies, lead was mentioned).  If you think it is a duplicate, go ahead.