# How to create a variable (that captures increases at a certain threshold) R?

Tags: r, function, machine-learning

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
    Subject  Year   X   Y   
        A   1990    1   0   
        A   1991    1   0   
        A   1992    2   0   
        A   1993    3   1   
        A   1994    4   0   
        A   1995    4   0   
        B   1990    0   0   
        B   1991    1   0   
        B   1992    1   0   
        B   1993    2   1   
        C   1991    1   0   
        C   1992    2   0   
        C   1993    3   0   
        C   1994    3   0   
        D   1991    1   0   
        D   1992    2   0   
        D   1993    3   0   
        D   1994    4   0   
        D   1995    5   0   
        D   1996    5   1   
        D   1997    6   0
```

How can I create two additional columns where

- A1 is 1 if X increased and the maximum for the subject is at least 4. Otherwise it is 0. I tried `data$A1 <- as.numeric(data$X  >4)` However, it's not quite what I want.
- A2 is a bit more complicated to explain and I have no clue how to perform it in R. But it basically has the same idea as A1 meaning that it still should capture all X's that are more than 3. Only, it should be = 1 when Y = 0 for the following 5 years. I give an example what the A2 variable should look like. Is it possible do this in R? Or do I need to do this manually?

Result:

```
            Subject  Year   X   A1   Y   A2
                A   1990    1    1   0    0
                A   1991    1    0   0    0
                A   1992    2    1   0    0
                A   1993    3    1   1    0
                A   1994    4    1   0    0
                A   1995    4    0   0    0
                B   1990    0    0   0    0
                B   1991    1    0   0    0
                B   1992    1    0   0    0 
                B   1993    2    0   1    0
                C   1991    1    0   0    0
                C   1992    2    0   0    0 
                C   1993    3    0   0    0 
                C   1994    3    0   0    0
                D   1991    1    1   0    1
                D   1992    2    1   0    1
                D   1993    3    1   0    1
                D   1994    4    1   0    1 
                D   1995    5    1   0    1 
                D   1996    5    0   1    0
                D   1997    6    1   0    0
```

Rawdata without the variables A1 and A2:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1993L, 1994L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L
), X = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), Y = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Subject", 
"Year", "X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L
))
```

Comment: You forgot to include the code you wrote that didn't work when you tried to solve these yourself.

Comment: @RichardScriven I'll do that soon, too

Comment: I don't understand: You already have the tables above as `data.frame`? What do you have, what do you need... Your question is quite long ;-)

Comment: @Christoph I would like to create variables X1, X2, A1, A2, and A3..:) Those are just examples of variables I want to creates, I only created the data.frame to illustrate which variable I want. I know, too long :(

Comment: Please read [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) How to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., abstract from your real problem... Then we can help you ;-) At the moment it is not clear, what you have and which part is missing.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks–very useful! I'll do that soon.

Comment: Ok. let me know. I can have a look at it on Friday if you like...

Comment: Some fodder for your repost: The variables you are trying to create are basically dummy variables. For the ones checking for 3 0's in a row etc, make new vectors which are just lags of the original column using the base R function lag(). Then you can just make a new column which checks the values of those vectors to create your new variable -- you could use the base R function ifelse() for this, thought there are prettier solutions. For the grouping you're trying to do, see this stack overflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/r-how-to-create-a-lag-variable-for-each-by-group.

Comment: The above is not a perfect way to do it, but should help you make a best effort at solving it when reposting. It's hard to give a better answer without more detail, as @Christoph mentioned. Can look again when more detail is posted.

Comment: dear @Christoph and verybadatthis: I've updated the question now and limited it to two related questions. Was not easy to explain must admit. Please have a look when you have the time. Cheers

Comment: Why is `A1` zero in this line: `B, 1991, 1, 0`?

Comment: Hi @Christoph! because the X variable never reached 4 (4 or more) for subject `B`. Basically if the X is more than 3 for any subject in the dataset, the dummy variable A1 should capture it. See for example Subject A and D.

Comment: Why the A1 is 0 for `B   1993    2    0` .  In the previous line, X is 1.

Comment: @akrun because subject B never reached 4 (A1 should capture increases only if subjects reach 4 or more in X)

Comment: @FKG I posted a solution.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, A1 := if(any(X >=4)) c(1, diff(X)) else 0, by = Subject]
data[,  A2 := if(any(X >=3))  inverse.rle(within.list(rle(Y==0), 
              values[values][lengths[values] < 5] <- 0)) else 0, by = Subject]

data[, c("Subject", "Year", "X", "A1", "Y", "A2"), with = FALSE]
#    Subject Year X A1 Y A2
# 1:       A 1990 1  1 0  0
# 2:       A 1991 1  0 0  0
# 3:       A 1992 2  1 0  0
# 4:       A 1993 3  1 1  0
# 5:       A 1994 4  1 0  0
# 6:       A 1995 4  0 0  0
# 7:       B 1990 0  0 0  0
# 8:       B 1991 1  0 0  0
# 9:       B 1992 1  0 0  0
#10:       B 1993 2  0 1  0
#11:       C 1991 1  0 0  0
#12:       C 1992 2  0 0  0
#13:       C 1993 3  0 0  0
#14:       C 1994 3  0 0  0
#15:       D 1991 1  1 0  1
#16:       D 1992 2  1 0  1
#17:       D 1993 3  1 0  1
#18:       D 1994 4  1 0  1
#19:       D 1995 5  1 0  1
#20:       D 1996 5  0 1  0
#21:       D 1997 6  1 0  0
```

Comment: I tried it on the bigger sample and it seems to work – many thanks!!! Although, for some reason, there are a lot of negative values generated when the X=0. I just deleted them, otherwise all looks good.

Comment: @FKG  Thanks for the feedback.  Probably, the X=0 condition was not taken into account.

Comment: Hi again. I'm working with this line: 
`setDT(data)[, A1 := if(any(X >=4)) c(1, diff(X)) else 0, by = Subject]`. 
Is it possible to adjust this part – _"if(any(X>=4))"_  – to something that would make the A1 capture when the X has reached 3 (not more than 3. If more than 3, then =0). I did try `"if(any(X=3))"` but then it only captured 3's in the X. I need it to capture 1's and 2's as well.

Comment: Just to be clear: if the X is more than 3 for a certain subject, for example, then the A1 should not capture it at all. Please let me if creating a new question would be a better way to address this

Comment: @FKG Can you please post it as a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383092/how-to-generate-a-range-variable-in-r here is the question. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385351/how-to-create-a-conditional-variable-in-r  Have a look at this one if you have the time. I've got help with the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Does that do the job? Do you need the Structure as factor? The code below does not yet realize the change in structure e.g. from C to D.

```
mydata <- structure("Your code here")
mydata$max <- rep(F, nrow(mydata))
mydata$A1 <- rep(0, nrow(mydata))
mydata$A2 <- rep(0, nrow(mydata))

for (i in unique(mydata$Subject)) {
  max <- max(mydata$X[mydata$Subject == i])
  if (max >=3) {
    mydata$max[mydata$Subject == i] <- T
  }
}
mydata$A1 <- ifelse(mydata$max & c(F,diff(mydata$X) > 0), 1, 0)
```

A2 is still unclear (See also my edit). Hopefully this helps to get the rest done.

Comment: many thanks for this, Christoph! I'm thinking what it does to my data. In the best of circumstances, it should realize the differences between subjects (or structure).

Comment: @FKG: If it worked, it would be great to mark the question as answered;-)