# How to generate a "range" variable in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
    Subject Year    X
       A    1990    1
       A    1991    1
       A    1992    2
       A    1993    3
       A    1994    4
       A    1995    4
       B    1990    0
       B    1991    1
       B    1992    1
       B    1993    2
       C    1991    1
       C    1992    2
       C    1993    3
       C    1994    3
       D    1991    1
       D    1992    2
       D    1993    3
       D    1994    4
       D    1995    5
       D    1996    5
       D    1997    6
```

I want to generate a binary(0/1) variable (let's say variable A) that indicates weather the X variables has reached 3 (or 1-3), for each Subject. If the X variable has reached 4 or more, the A should not capture it.

It should look like this:

```
Subject Year    X   A
   A    1990    1   0
   A    1991    1   0
   A    1992    2   0
   A    1993    3   0
   A    1994    4   0
   A    1995    4   0
   B    1990    0   0
   B    1991    1   0
   B    1992    1   0
   B    1993    2   0
   C    1991    1   1
   C    1992    2   1
   C    1993    3   1
   C    1994    3   1
   D    1991    1   0
   D    1992    2   0
   D    1993    3   0
   D    1994    4   0
   D    1995    5   0
   D    1996    5   0
   D    1997    6   0
```

I tried the following: `mydata$A<- as.numeric(mydata$X %in% 1:3)`but it doesn't control for the continuation....

A reproducible sample:

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1993L, 1994L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L
), X = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("Subject", "Year", 
"X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

All suggestions are welcome – thanks!

Comment: So A should be 1 if the maximum x value is 3?

Comment: If subject `E` had values of 2 and 3, would you want to flag it? Or does it have to be 1,2,3? How about 2,3,1...

Comment: Honestly speaking, the question is not clear. Help users to help you by providing a clear question.

Comment: @SabDeM Please let me what's not clear. I'll try to make it clear.

Comment: @docendodiscimus that's right. couldn't put it better

Comment: @zx8754 sorry, I wasn't clear. The X is a cumulative variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R one-liner use `ave`:

```
df$A <- ave(df$X, df$Subject, FUN = function(x) if (max(x) == 3) 1 else 0)

> df
   Subject Year X A
1        A 1990 1 0
2        A 1991 1 0
3        A 1992 2 0
4        A 1993 3 0
5        A 1994 4 0
6        A 1995 4 0
7        B 1990 0 0
8        B 1991 1 0
9        B 1992 1 0
10       B 1993 2 0
11       C 1991 1 1
12       C 1992 2 1
13       C 1993 3 1
14       C 1994 3 1
15       D 1991 1 0
16       D 1992 2 0
17       D 1993 3 0
18       D 1994 4 0
19       D 1995 5 0
20       D 1996 5 0
21       D 1997 6 0
```

Comment: You have `C 1994 3 1` , but OP says it should be 0

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question but I think I could post it as a new question. But this code worked well!

Comment: also just `(ave(df$X, df$Subject, FUN = max) == 3) + 0` probably

Comment: @Zelazny7 If you have the time, please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385351/how-to-create-a-conditional-variable-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Then, if you only want to capture increases, with shift function you can access to other rows. This solution works, but first value is NA because it hasn't nothing to compare with

```
mydata$A <- ifelse(mydata$X > shift(mydata$X, 1L, type="lag"), 1,0)
```