# How to create a lag variable within each group? [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, data-processing

My question is similar to this [question about creating a lag variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/how-to-create-a-lag-variable-within-each-group).  All I need to do is to implement this code in `Matlab`.

For instance let's say we have the following two vectors in `Matlab`:

```
ID =[2;2;2;2;3;3;5;5]
Pur=[0;1;2;3;1;2;4;5]
[ID,Pur]
ans =

 2     0
 2     1
 2     2
 2     3
 3     1
 3     2
 5     4
 5     5
```

I am looking for a way to lag the `Purchase` variable for each ID. To get something like:

```
ans =

2     NA
2     0
2     1
2     2
3     NA
3     1
5     NA
5     4
```

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and what haven't work, and what confuses you. SO is not a coding service. Also, please expand a little on the characteristics of your data, for example, would the ID's would always be grouped and sorted, or could their locations be randomized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way I found for this:

```
ID =[2;2;2;2;3;3;5;5]
Pur=[0;1;2;3;1;2;4;5]

[uniqueValues,~,uniqueIndex] = unique(ID)

n = numel(uniqueValues);  

shop_sess = accumarray(uniqueIndex,1);

shop_sess_cum=cumsum(shop_sess)
shop_sess_r=[0;shop_sess_cum2(1:length(shop_sess_cum)-1)]

lagPur=[]

for i=1:n
shop_sess_r_i=shop_sess_r(i)    
shop_sess_i=shop_sess_cum(i)
temp=Pur(shop_sess_r_i+1:shop_sess_i)
lagtemp=lagmatrix(temp,1)
lagPur=[lagPur;lagtemp]
end
```