# Add rows with the values in the earlier/previous date

Tags: r

I wish to have the factor that happened earlier as a new row.

This is my data

```
df <- data.frame (id =c(1,1,2,2,1), date= c(20161002,20151019, 20160913, 20161117, 20160822),  factor = c("A" , "B" ,"C" ,"D" ,"H"))
```

and I want to have an additional row that shows the immediate last factor. So, my ideal output is:

```
 id   date   factor   col2
1  1 20161002      A    H
2  1 20151019      B    NA
3  2 20160913      C    NA
4  2 20161117      D    C
5  1 20160822      H    B
```

For instance, for id 1 in the **first row** the previous factor happend in 20160822 and its value was `H`.

What I tied does not consider the last date

```
library (dplyr)
library(zoo)
mutate( col2 = na.locf(factor))
```

Comment: Not clear. How previous factor for `20161002` is `20160822` ? and how `20151019` is `NA` ?

Comment: For `id 1` we have two dates before `20161002` which are '20151019` and `20160822 ` the immediate last one is `20160822` isn't it true? For 20151019 we do not have a factor before that for id 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/how-to-create-a-lag-variable-within-each-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this

```
library(data.table)
df$date = as.Date(as.character(df$date),"%Y%m%d")

setDT(df)
setorder(df,id,date)

df[, "col2" := shift(factor), by = .(id)]
id       date factor col2
1:  1 2015-10-19      B   NA
2:  1 2016-08-22      H    B
3:  1 2016-10-02      A    H
4:  2 2016-09-13      C   NA
5:  2 2016-11-17      D    C
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`. Convert the character `date` to Date format. Then we sort the date by group (`id`) using `arrange` and select the last `factor` using `lag`.

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date), "%Y%m%d")
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(date) %>%
   mutate(col2 = lag(factor))

#    id    date     factor   col2
#    <dbl> <date>    <fctr> <fctr>
#1     1 2015-10-19      B     NA
#2     1 2016-08-22      H      B
#3     2 2016-09-13      C     NA
#4     1 2016-10-02      A      H
#5     2 2016-11-17      D      C
```