# lag row value in R by groups

Tags: r

I want the previous row value for different groups. I have gone through the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/how-to-create-a-lag-variable-within-each-group) and also tried the code shown below.

```
new_data[,avg_week := shift(.(avg_travel_time),type = "lag"), by = identifier]
```

This is the error that I am getting.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(new_data, , `:=`(avg_week, c(NA, avg_travel_time[-.N])),  : 
unused argument (by = identifier)
```

Comment: You have a typo.  no need for `.(` inside `shift` `new_data[,avg_week := shift(avg_travel_time, type = "lag"), by = identifier]`

Comment: Still the same error '> new_data[,avg_week := shift(avg_travel_time, type = "lag"), by = identifier]
Error in `[.data.frame`(new_data, , `:=`(avg_week, shift(avg_travel_time,  : 
  unused argument (by = identifier)'

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the OP's code, 1) the dataset is a `data.frame` and not a `data.table`, 2) use of `.(` inside `shift` which is not required.  We need to first convert to `data.table` (`setDT(new_data)` before applying the `data.table` syntax

```
setDT(new_data)[,avg_week := shift(avg_travel_time, type = "lag"), by = identifier]
```