# Calculate average by group and starting in an specific date, in R

Tags: r, dplyr, moving-average, panel-data

Here we have a panel data of "pessoas contadas" (counted people) in the city of Rio de Janeiro, by "dia" (day) and "bairro" (neighborhood). I want to calculate the average of counted people, by "bairro", in the last n days, according to the day 24/03/2020. The result must be repeated along the role panel, by "bairro". How can I do it?

You can download the dataset here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz5fkgs0vuyoi8s/teste.xlsx?dl=0

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "The result must be repeated along the role panel, by 'bairro'"? Do you want to calculate a rolling mean?

Comment: No, I want the same result calculated to be repeated along the.

Comment: Could you post your desired output? It might help us to understand what you're trying to do to get an answer

Comment: I've found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/how-to-create-a-lag-variable-within-each-group.