# compare two consecutive values in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df like this in R:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 6 |
| b | 13 |
| c | 9 |
| c | 16 |
| c | 17 |
| c | 23 |

I want a new column df$C, which substracts the value in B2 from the value in B1, if A2 = A1 and substracts the value in B3 from the value in B2, if A3 = A2 and so on ...
Just like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 6 | 6 |
| b | 13 | 13 |
| c | 9 | 9 |
| c | 16 | 7 |
| c | 17 | 1 |
| c | 23 | 6 |

I tried to write a simple ifelse-function, but don't know how I can compare two consecutively values in the same column.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(A) %>%mutate(C = B - lag(B, default = 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[building on others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/how-to-create-a-lag-variable-within-each-group):

`lag()` cannot work here, it has to be emulated, because the first value in the new column will have to be an `NA` by definition, as there is nothing to compare the first value to.

Building on @BPeif's answer:

```
df$A2=c(NA, df$A[-nrow(df)])
df$B2=c(NA, df$B[-nrow(df)])

df$C = ifelse(df$A2 == df$A, df$B - df$B2, df$B)
```

Comment: You are right my solution does not work for the first observation as i did not care about the NA. I tried your solution and it did not work neither on me, but thanks to your answer i edited mine, it should be good now. Thanks !

Comment: funny. for me it works fine. The comparison of NA with anything returns NA and thus an NA in the result of `ifelse`

Answer (score 4):

The lag() function from the dplyr package provides the previous observation:

```
df = data.frame("A" = c("a","b","c","c","c","c"),
                "B" = c(6,13,9,16,17,23))

library(dplyr)

df$A2 = dplyr::lag(df$A)
df$B2 = dplyr::lag(df$B)
```

Then adding the C and substract the needed columns:

```
df$C = ifelse(is.na(df$A2)==FALSE & df$A2 == df$A, df$B - df$B2, df$B)
df <- df %>% select(A, B, C)
```

Should work !

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the easy question. I'm quite new to R.

Comment: `lag` only works on time series... at least for me... I just tried it, since me too didn't know about the function but it just returns a copy of the input-vector. Can I learn something about that?

Comment: @MauriceHüttemann Sorry for the 'easily', just meant that this function was easy to handle, but i am new as well and just try to help with the few knowledge i have ! I edited, because as said TobiO the NA was not handled in my solution

Comment: @TobiO There is the lag() function in the dplyr package, that is not the same as the stats package.

Comment: thanks for the clarification :-)

as usually base R trumps dplyr, the invocation should be `dplyr::lag()`

Comment: Yeah you right ! I can change that too